# Control de acceso a mi pagina web

Tags: php, web, seguridad, cpanel

soy nuevo en estas cosas y me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de hacer que ciertas computadoras puedan accesar a mi dominio pero no me gustaría hacerlo con PIs, quiero saber si hay alguna forma de instalar algo en el navegador o en la computadora y que eso le de acceso a mi pagina y si no lo tiene que no pueda acceder estoy usando WHM/cPanel se que tiene firewall pero es solo por IPs 
mi pagina la tengo con PHP, si alguien supiera de algo o tenga una idea de como hacerlo me ayudaría mucho.

El problema es que alguien intento accesar en horario no laboral desde su casa e hizo un ataque con SQL injection con fuerza bruta si validamos el acceso con IPs, esta persona podria copiar la IP desde el navegador y evitar la seguridad, necesito una forma de que solo las computadoras de la compañía puedan accesar al sitio y si alguien intenta accesar desde otro lado ellos no puedan ver ninguna pagina o que el sitio simplemente los redireccione.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

creo que la respuesta puede ser con un `.htacces`, lo unico que tienes que hacer es crear el archivo `.htacces` en la carpeta donde esta lo que quieres protejer y introducir el codigo:

```html
order allow,deny
allow from (tu ip)
deny from all
```

Lo que estarias haciendo es *permitir* a (**ip**) tener acceso a los archivos y *bloquear* a los demas, si quieres agregar otra (**ip**) solo tienes que agregar otro `allow from (ip)`, *si estoy equivocado por favor indicamelo y borrare la publicacion*. Gracias

Comment: si pensé en eso pero se puede evadir la seguridad fácilmente con un VPN,

Comment: segun mi definicion de VPN te ofrese una ip distinta (no puedes cambiarla)